# RuntimeError: Unknown runtime 'nodejs8'

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

When I try to run my nodeJS dev_app server locally to test my app.yaml file, I am getting this error:

> RuntimeError: Unknown runtime 'nodejs8'; supported runtimes are
>   'custom', 'go', 'java', 'java7', 'java8', 'php55', 'php72', 'python',
>   'python-compat', 'python27', 'python37'.

However Google announced that NodeJS is now supported with AppEngine standard environment. Here's my app.yaml file:

```
runtime: nodejs8
service: front
handlers:
  - url: /.*\.[jpg|css|js|svg|ttf]
    secure: always
    redirect_http_response_code: 301
    static_files: public/\1
    upload: public/.*

  - url: /.*
    secure: always
    script: bin/start
```

PS: I updated my google cloud SDK, the current version is 209.0.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlike for other standard environment supported languages, for node.js local development doesn't appear to be using the SDK-supplied development server, which is probably why you  see that error when trying to run that server. From [Running locally](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/testing-and-deploying-your-app#running_locally):

> To test your application's functionality before deploying, run your
>   application in your local environment with the development tools that
>   you usually use.
>
> For example, `npm start`.

Comment: Actually, I just want to test the app.yaml file, not testing the application. I want to test the handlers part especially.

Comment: To test the static handlers you could temporarily set the runtime to `python27` (don't forget to set it back when done) to keep the server happy. You may need to also add a python app skeleton or try commenting out the `script` portion. You can't test the dynamic handlers anyways, node.js only accepts `auto` (which BTW you don't have)

Comment: What do you meet with `auto` can you give more details ?

Comment: From [doc](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/config/appref#handlers_element): The only accepted value for the `script` element is `auto`.

Comment: Oh ok ! thanks ^^ I changed it, it doesn't really matter what I put in this field. But it's more correct that way

Comment: I accept this answer, even if I am still not able to test the app.yaml locally.